# Decode JPEG image scan data with Huffman tables

Tags: python, jpeg, huffman-code, dct

I'm writing a decoder for reading the raw data stream of a jpeg and converting it to the pixel values. I am at the stage where I have constructed the Huffman trees and need to use them to decode the image scan which comes after the SOS segment. I understand that the decoding process is different depending on the APPn marker, but I can't find details on the decoding process itself. I'm getting four separate AC Huffman trees in a baseline jpeg, what I'm confused by is which tree is supposed to be used for decoding. The trees seem to have overlapping values so I can't just apply all of the trees to the decoding process. So assuming a baseline encoded jpeg, how do I figure out which huffman trees to use for decoding the image scan as well as where to use them in the scan?

Comment: This is exactly what is described in detail in the standard.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only source I know of that explains the process without academic mumbo-jumbo:

[https://www.amazon.com/Compressed-Image-File-Formats-JPEG/dp/0201604434](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201604434)

One huffman table is used per scan. You only use one for each. A single scan can share huffman tables with another. The SOS marker specifies which huffman table to use with the scan.